# flash drive as swap is not used

Tags: swap-space

I'v added a flash drive as swap and formated it with code 82 (Swap).
Additionally, I've added the uuid (out of `blkid`) to `/etc/fstab`.
After reboot I see that no swap is being used.

What's wrong?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/usbstick $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1  57.9G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    1  57.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb           8:16   1 233.3G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   1 233.3G  0 part /mnt/usbstick
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59.5G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0    24G  0 part /
```

Output of swapon

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/usbstick $ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition       60652540        0       -2
```

Before changing that, my swap was continuously at 100 / 100 MB.
I expected to see at least that amount of used memory.

Comment: It appears to me that you have about 60 GB of swap space on your flash drive. What did you expect? I have to say that using a flash drive for swap does not sound like a good idea to me...writes are very slow.

Comment: I had two motivations: Swap was always full (100 MB) while reading that twice the phsical memory is recommended and I wanted to limit the write access to the sd card. This lead me to the idea to use a pen drive as swap. That 60 GB flash drive was simple available and not in use, so I took it, even tough it seems much to large. Speed is not that issue. What I miss is, that the swap is actually being used.

Comment: What does `free` say about memory use?

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          924Mi       286Mi       201Mi       8.0Mi       436Mi       545Mi
Swap:          57Gi       199Mi        57Gi`
Seems that swap is now in use and this question is obsolete. Does that look fine from your perspective? @ElliotAlderson

Comment: It does look like your swap is working. Good luck!